# cannot found file of fonts in vue

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

aim using vue cli 3,and
i have file inside of
iam writng my code in fonts.scss file and iam write like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ElMessiri';
    src: url('./fonts/ElMessiri/ElMessiri-VariableFont_wght.ttf') format(' truetype');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
  }
```

then i imported in to components like this

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "../css/Main.scss";
 @import "../css/font.scss";
</style>
```

Note that the font file is available,
then ihave this eroor  :
This dependency was not found:

- @/fonts/ElMessiri/ElMessiri-VariableFont_wght.ttf in

Comment: That means your URL is wrong, what is the file structure?

Comment: no this is my path : fonts/ElMessiri/ElMessiri-VariableFont_wght.ttf  , iam sure and File structure for font just

Answer (score 1):

I found what the problem is, just replace the world (url) in font-face to (local) thats it...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks it's work for me, I'm trying from so many times.